# How can friction be a canditate for centripetal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

What if a car goes around a circular track of really large radius say 2018 km? Would friction act towards the centre, i.e perpendicular to direction of velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You turn your wheels, and that causes a perpendicular friction component. Such a component causes the direction to turn. It can be small or little; regardless, this turning can become a circular path and the inwards centripetal force causing it was friction.

This phenomenon is called *traction*.

Answer (score 0):

There are some circular curves along which a car can drive that do not involve friction at all. A track can be banked so that, given the right speed, the normal force is the only force needed to sustain circular motion. On a larger scale, a locally flat, earth-spanning equatorial highway would not require friction to sustain circular motion.

However, just because it is possible to construct circular courses that do not require friction to sustain circular motion does not rule out friction as a requirement in other cases. Saying that those courses that do not need friction to sustain circular rules out friction in general is a logical fallacy.